# jquerymobile: how to catch ajax loading success

Tags: jquery-mobile

As jquerymobile loads the internal pages using Ajax request, if I want to do some actions after loading the internal page how to kknow the onload event?

Thanks,
nehatha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/docs/api/events.html

Example:

```
$('div').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
  alert('This page was just hidden: '+ ui.prevPage);
});
```

> **pagebeforeshow** 
> Triggered on the page being shown, before its
> transition begins.
>
> **pagebeforehide** 
> Triggered on the page being hidden, before its
> transition begins.
>
> **pageshow** 
> Triggered on the page being shown, after its transition
> completes.
>
> **pagehide** 
> Triggered on the page being hidden, after its transition
> completes.